# exact differences between so that such that

Tags: adverbs

He was disappeared such that

He was disappeared so that

Would you complete those sentences in such a way that they would be meaningful?

In addition, I think the more appreciate phrase for either of the sentences would be the following instead of such that or so that, wouldn't it?

in a way that

Thanks in advance

Comment: [*such that*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/such-that) is *so that*.

Answer (score 1):

Such that is used to show the meaning: to the extent that:

example include:

> My naivety about property prices is such that I thought I'd discovered a new bit of London.
>
> The popularity of the song was such that it was repeatedly played at
>   the festival venue.

So that indicates purpose; in order that.

> He must die so that others might live.

In your sentence all three phrases (so that, such that and in a way that) are possible depending upon the context of the whole sentence.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would probably start these sentences using *had* instead of *was*, or maybe use *disappeared* on its own:

> He had disappeared so that...
>
> He had disappeared such that...
>
> He disappeared so that...

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/so-that) mentions that the phrase *so that* is used to "introduce a clause of purpose".

For example:

> You should wash your hands so that you don't catch a cold.
> I left the door unlocked so that John could let himself in.

So, if you can think of a reason someone would disappear, you can use *so that* to introduce that reason:

> Ed had two arrest warrants. When he heard the police at the door, he disappeared so that he would not be arrested.

It's worth pointing out – we can omit the *that* and these sentences would still be grammatically correct:

> You should wash your hands so you don't catch a cold.
> I left the door unlocked so John could let himself in.
> He disappeared so he would not be arrested.

Collins also mentions that *such that* can indicate purpose [or result](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/such-that). I would say that, when indicating a purpose or reason, *so that* generally sounds more natural than *such that*:

> You should wash your hands such that you don't catch a cold.
> I left the door unlocked such that John could let himself in.
> He disappeared such that he would not be arrested.

For those three sentences, I prefer the sentences that use *so* or *so that* (although I'm not sure I could go so far as to say *such that* would be incorrect or ungrammatical).

However, *such that* can be used to express the result of the disappearance:

> The hobbit put on the ring. The moment he did, he disappeared such that we could not see him.
>
> Ed had disappeared such that the police could not arrest him.

As an aside, in the first sentence, "disappear" has a more literal meaning.